# Provide a negative score when not matched in Elasticsearch Query

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am working on a crazy requirement, crazy because I have never done that and from the look of it I don't think it can be done directly. Looking for help in this platform if someone can help me out.

The requirement is in Elasticsearch if a value matches then I have to provide a score, but if the field is present but doesn't matches then provide a negative score which when latter summed will decrease the score. 
Example lets say I am searching for two fields name and subject. If name matches then the score provided is 50, if subject is match then the score is 10 . So if both matches then score is 60. If subject is not matched then score is -10 which when gets added gives me 40.

This is easy in terms of some programming language but unable to do so in Elasticsearch query. I am using function scoring, below is sample query.
Any help in this regard is appreciated.

```
GET dummy_rps_index_2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "dis_max": {
            "queries": [
              {
                "function_score": {
                  "boost_mode": "replace",
                  "score_mode": "max",
                  "max_boost": 100,
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "disable_coord": true,
                      "minimum_should_match": 1,
                      "should": [
                        {
                          "function_score": {
                            "score_mode": "max",
                            "boost_mode": "replace",
                            "_name": "name_match",
                            "query": {
                              "multi_match": {
                                "query": "TIFFIN",
                                "fields": [
                                "name"
                                ],
                                "operator": "or",
                                "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                              }
                            },
                            "functions": [
                              {
                                "filter": {
                                  "multi_match": {
                                    "query": "TIFFIN",
                                    "fields": [
                                      "name"
                                    ],
                                    "operator": "or",
                                    "fuzziness": 0
                                  }
                                },
                                "weight": 50
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "function_score": {
                            "score_mode": "max",
                            "boost_mode": "replace",
                            "_name": "multipleline_code",
                            "query": {
                              "bool": {
                                "disable_coord": true,
                                "minimum_should_match": 1,
                                "should": [
                                  {
                                    "function_score": {
                                      "boost_mode": "replace",
                                      "query": {
                                        "multi_match": {
                                          "query": "maths",
                                          "fields": [
                                            "subject
                                          ]
                                        }
                                      },
                                      "functions": [
                                        {
                                          "weight": 10
                                        }
                                      ]
                                    }
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]                      
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Negative weight are not allowed in function weight.
Using must and must_not in function filter different scores can be assigned.

Data:

```
[
      {
        "_index" : "index28",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "bJLH2G0Bti9Q-XOmRxgV",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "John",
          "subject" : "Math"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index28",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "bZLH2G0Bti9Q-XOmcxia",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "John",
          "subject" : "English"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "name": "John"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "match": {
                    "subject": "English"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "weight": 60
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "name": "John"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "must_not": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "subject": "English"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "weight": 40
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must_not": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "name": "John"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "must": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "subject": "English"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "weight": 10
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "sum"
    }
  }
}
```